# Calling Javascript alert from Java Servlet before generating JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I've seen many topics about on this title, but I would need something different.

How to invoke simple JavaScript alert() method, during Servlet's executing without breaking it's execution (jumping on client side)?

For example here's conception of what I would like to create if it's possible:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

    // CODE
    // JavaScript's Alert('Hello')
    // CODE
    // response.sendRedirect('page.jsp')    

}
```

So client will only see Hello and after it, *page.jsp* is been generated.

Comment: Are you trying to get `alert()` to be run on page.jsp, after the user has come from a certain page?

Comment: JavaScript is built within the page/JSP, there is no way you can do it.

Comment: @pleasedesktop No matter where I get alert(), I need just to warn user about result of Servlet, so I would need either on first or second page.

Comment: Servlets execute code on the server. `alert()` is usually executed on the client's web browser, if at all. You cannot execute `alert()` in a servlet, but you can get the servlet to output JavaScript that calls `alert()` and hence which will run on the client's web browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the desired result using `Dispatch` process.

**Servlet.java:**

```
request.setAttribute("alertName", "Sample Result");
request.getRequestDispatcher("page.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

If you want to warn the user before the `page.jsp` starts up using the result you desired in your `servlet`. you can use the below code to retrieve the result and put it in the `alert()` method before the page load.

**page.jsp:**

```
<body>
    <input id="alertName" type="hidden" value="${alertName}"/>
</body>
```

above code will input the value of `alertName` to input element that is hidden, because we can't directly put it in the JavaScript because it process client side only. BTW `${alertName}` is retrieve using EL(Expression Language), it process on server side that's why we can't directly put it in the JavaScript.

```
<script>
       $(window).load(function() {
           var alertName = $("#alertName").val(); // retrive using the ID of the input
           alert(alertName);  // The prompt will alert "Sample Result"
       });
</script>
```

Comment: I would need depending on the result of Servlet to send him different warnings.

Comment: @luka032 I edited it. you can use dispatch to pass result from servlet to JSP.

Comment: Thanks a lot, great response!